# Могу ли я использовать классы или Фасады на странице Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel

Иногда необходимо использовать классы например модель User  или фасад Carbon.

Могу ли я использовать название класса или фасада на странице   blade ?

Comment: можно. просто пиши что нужно между <?php ?> - подключай там фасады, Carbon  и т.п. Но это не круто.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще не лучший подход пихать это во вьюшки! Логикой должен заниматься контроллер (например, получением нужных записей из БД), а за формат вывода может вполне отвечать модель.

Например, получаем первого попавшегося пользователя в контроллере и передаем его во вью:

```
public function getFirstUser()
{
    $user = Users::firstOrFail();
    return view('myview')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Если мы хотим вывести дату создания пользователя в другом формате, то можно в модели использовать мутатор:

```
public function getMyDateFormatAttribute()
{
    if (isset($this->attributes['created_at'])) {
        return Carbon::parse($this->attributes['created_at'])->format('d.m.Y');
    }
}
```

После этого во вьюшке можно вывести дату в нужном нам формате:

```
{{ $user->myDateFormat }}
```

Получим: dd.mm.yyyy

Подробнее о мутаторах:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 0):

Во фреймворка не предусмотрен такой вариант и при попытке просто подключить модель в шаблоне через require_once или include_once будет выдаваться предупреждение или ошибка. Лучше подключайте и используйте эти классы в контроллере и в нем же передавайте результаты вычислений в определенный шаблон.

Comment: На странице  blade  могу использовать carbon,  используя полное название Carbon\Carbon , как видите ни каких require  не понадобилось

Comment: А модель получается так подключить?

Comment: Думаю возможно ,  например App\User

Comment: Ну тогда в чем вопрос? Подключайте

Comment: Просто хотел узнать правильная ли это практика, или нужно остерегаться  такого подхода